Command fails through Dockerfile build but works manually
I am trying to build the following Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD ["/start.sh"]

But Docker spits the following error:
root@VM:~/playground/docker/web# docker build .
[+] Building 10.4s (6/8)                                                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 163B                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++                                                                                                                                     10.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 29B                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++:                                                                                                                                                 
0.270 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                        
5.275 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                   
5.275 WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main: temporary error (try again later)
10.28 WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community: temporary error (try again later)
10.28 ERROR: unable to select packages:
10.28   g++ (no such package):
10.28     required by: world[g++]
10.28   gcc (no such package):
10.28     required by: world[gcc]
10.28   make (no such package):
10.28     required by: world[make]
10.28   python3 (no such package):
10.28     required by: world[python3]
10.28   yarn (no such package):
10.28     required by: world[yarn]
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM node:18-alpine
   2 |     
   3 | >>> RUN apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++
   4 |     ADD start.sh /
   5 |     RUN chmod +x /start.sh
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++" did not complete successfully: exit code: 5

So it fails at stepRUN apk add --no-cache yarn python3 make gcc g++. But then I ran the same command from a container ( using docker run -it node:18-alpine /bin/sh) and it worked!
This is not an intermittent network issue as I tried running the command multiple times with the same result.
What could cause the same command to work in shell but fail when running though docker build despite being in the same network?

temporary error (try again later) - Then you did. And it worked...

@OneCricketeer I wrote "This is not an intermirrent network issue as I tried running the command multiple times with the same result."

What if you add RUN apk update first?

Actually I was able to build using docker build --network host . Then I specified a DNS in /etc/docker/daemon.json and this allowed me to build without the --network flag. So apparently the network stack used when building containers is not the same one for running them...

That sounds like a bug in Docker or BuildKit – you should almost never need --network host for anything.
